# "slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds" exception when using tf.data dataset API with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tired to use tf.data api to load mnist dataset to train a simple model as below, but got "slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds" exception. I was wondering what I did wrong in my code.

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 32


def load_data():
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
    (train_data, train_label), (validation_data, validation_label) = mnist.load_data()
    train_data, validation_data = train_data / 255.0, validation_data / 255.0
    train_label = train_label.astype(np.float32)
    return train_data, train_label


def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


train_data, train_label = load_data()
train_sample_count = len(train_data)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()

iter = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
train_x, train_y = iter.get_next()


model = build_model()
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(train_sample_count/batch_size)
)
```

The full stacktrace is as below

> Epoch 1/10
>
> 2018-08-23 16:14:49.485165: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
>
> 2018-08-23 16:15:25.588057: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at strided_slice_op.cc:105 : Invalid argument: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
>
> 2018-08-23 16:15:26.852912: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at iterator_ops.cc:910 : Cancelled:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/xievi/workspace/speaker_verification/mnist_with_dataset.py", line 35, in
>
> steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(train_sample_count/batch_size)
>
> File "/Users/xievi/shared_python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1363, in fit
>
> validation_steps=validation_steps)
>
> File "/Users/xievi/shared_python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 205, in fit_loop
>      outs = f(ins)
>
> File "/Users/xievi/shared_python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 2914, in **call**
>
> fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
>
> File "/Users/xievi/shared_python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1382, in **call**
>
> run_metadata_ptr)
>
> File "/Users/xievi/shared_python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in **exit**
>
> c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
>
> [[Node: flatten/strided_slice = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](flatten/Shape, metrics/acc/Const, training/TFOptimizer/gradients/dense_1/Softmax_grad/Sum/reduction_indices, training/TFOptimizer/gradients/dense_1/Softmax_grad/Sum/reduction_indices)]]

Comment: The error that I see when I run your code is this. `ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=<RepeatDataset shapes: ((?, 28, 28), (?,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float32)>`

Comment: Thanks @MohanRadhakrishnan for looking into this. This is strange. I'm on Tensorflow 1.10 and Python 3.6. What are your versions?

Comment: Strangely, if I turn on eager mode, the code will run without this exception. However, the model does not seem to learn anything, as the accuracy hovers around 10%.

Comment: Moreover, if I rewrite the model as a custom model class (and not using eager mode), the exception also disappears. But again, the model does not seem to learn anything. I posted another question for this new problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999636/keras-model-failed-to-learn-anything-after-changing-to-use-tf-data-api

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, I'll share my fix.

This is the error I was getting:

```
ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1, strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```

This error prevented my Keras model from training. I tried changing the data pipline from Keras custom generator to tf.data, but the error didn't go. Finally, I was able to make it start training by changing the loss function from:

```
loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
```

To:

```
loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
```

I don't know the reason but this works for me.

Here is the full trace of my error:

```
    Epoch 1/100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify_cnn_generator.py", line 175, in <module>
    history = model.fit(train_generator, 
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 696, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3065, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:748 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:212 __call__
        batch_dim = array_ops.shape(y_t)[0]
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1013 _slice_helper
        return strided_slice(
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1186 strided_slice
        op = gen_array_ops.strided_slice(
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:10347 strided_slice
        _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:742 _apply_op_helper
        op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:591 _create_op_internal
        return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3477 _create_op_internal
        ret = Operation(
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1974 __init__
        self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
    /home/deogun/alali/.conda/envs/mytf2.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1815 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1, strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```