# Keras model failed to learn anything after changing to use tf.data api

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was trying to convert a simple Keras model to use tf.data api for data loading, but somehow the accuracy remains about 10% during the whole 10 epochs.

In comparison, the original code without using tf.data api can easily achieve about 98% accuracy. Did I do anything wrong?

The version using tf.data api

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 32


def load_data():
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
    (train_data, train_label), (validation_data, validation_label) = mnist.load_data()
    train_data, validation_data = train_data / 255.0, validation_data / 255.0
    train_label = train_label.astype(np.float32)
    return train_data, train_label


def build_model():
    class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

        def __init__(self):
            super(MyModel, self).__init__(name='my_model')
            self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
            self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
            self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
            self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

        def call(self, inputs):
            x = self.flatten(inputs)
            x = self.dense_1(x)
            x = self.dropout(x)
            y = self.dense_2(x)
            return y

    model = MyModel()

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


train_data, train_label = load_data()
train_sample_count = len(train_data)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()

model = build_model()
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=10,
  steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(train_sample_count/batch_size)
)
```

The version without using tf.data api

```
# load_data and build_model are exactly same as those in the tf.data api version

train_data, train_label = load_data()
model = build_model()
model.fit(
    train_data,
    train_label,
    epochs=10
)
```

Comment: I am also getting this behavior, both with your code and with my own code using mnist dataset. Two things: 1) The model DOES seem to be trained, since the loss is decreasing in the same way for both numpy and tf.data. It is the accuracy calculation that seems to be bugged. 2) I couldn't make the number of steps to look the same for both approaches: numpy says 60000 while tf.data says 1850. My version of tensorflow: 1.11.0-dev20180907.
If you come across a solution, please do share. Otherwise this can be a bug, to be reported.

Comment: In relation to point 1) in my comment above, try to use some other metric. For example, instead of  `metrics=['accuracy']`, try to use `metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy, tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_crossentropy]`. These seem to be calculated consistently.

Comment: I also created https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22190