# training loss decreases but the model doesn't learn when i use tensorflow.data api

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm training a classification model with 4 classes. When I use the data-generator with `numpy` arrays the model is trained well, the loss decreases, and the predictions are good.

But when I train the same model for exactly the same number of epochs with the same parameters, the training loss does decrease to almost the same value but the prediction accuracy even on the training dataset is below 50%.

I've explored the following links:

[Keras model failed to learn anything after changing to use tf.data api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999636/keras-model-failed-to-learn-anything-after-changing-to-use-tf-data-api)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22190)

I made adjustments to my loss function (from `categorical_crossentropy` to `tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy`), but the problem still persists. I'm using `tensorflow-gpu 2.0`.

**Edit:** This is the class I'm using to generate dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from glob import glob
import os
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

And here is my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2



"""
This generator is an abstract class as 
"""
class TfrecordLoader(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, dataset_path, batch_size=10):

        # Load the tfrecords
        video_paths = glob(os.path.join(dataset_path,"*.tfrecord"))
        self._dataset_len = len(video_paths)

        # Deserialize the tfrecords based on the below format
        def _parse_dicom_feature_record_function(serialized_data):

            # Deserialize the data
            dicom_feature_description = {
                'NUM_FRAMES': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'HEIGHT': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'WIDTH': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'CHANNEL_DEPTH': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
#                 'LVEF': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32),
                'IMAGE_QUALITY': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'RECORD_NAME': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'VIEW_TYPE': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'FRAMES_ARRAY': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            }
            return tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_data, dicom_feature_description)

        self._video_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(video_paths).map(_parse_dicom_feature_record_function)


        # The actual dataset used by this iterator randomly samples the frames of the passed data
        self._batch_size = batch_size
        self._iterator = self._create_iterator()
        return

    """
    Create iterator that iterates through loaded tfrecords.  Note, this is intended to be overloaded for more 
    specific traigins cases based on this dataset
    """
    def _create_iterator(self):
        # Return an iterator to that data
        return iter(self._video_dataset.shuffle(self._dataset_len).batch(self._batch_size))

    """
    Give the length of and epoch
    """
    def __len__(self):
        return math.floor(self._dataset_len / self._batch_size)

    """
    Returns one batch of data
    """
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return next(self._iterator)

    """
    Called at the end of each epic to select a new shuffled balanced dataset
    """
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        print ('\n\n ------------------------- EPOCH END ------------------------ \n\n')
        self._iterator = self._create_iterator()
        return

    """
    Convenience method for converting a tfrecord from this dataset into a traditional python dictionary
    """
    def convert_tfrecorddata_to_dict(self, record, batch_index):
        converted_dict = {}
        converted_dict['NUM_FRAMES'] = int(record['NUM_FRAMES'][batch_index])
        converted_dict['HEIGHT'] = int(record['HEIGHT'][batch_index])
        converted_dict['WIDTH'] = int(record['WIDTH'][batch_index])
        converted_dict['CHANNEL_DEPTH'] = int(record['CHANNEL_DEPTH'][batch_index])
#         converted_dict['LVEF'] = float(record['LVEF'][batch_index])
        converted_dict['IMAGE_QUALITY'] = record['IMAGE_QUALITY'][batch_index].numpy().decode()
        converted_dict['RECORD_NAME'] = record['RECORD_NAME'][batch_index].numpy().decode()
        converted_dict['VIEW_TYPE'] = record['VIEW_TYPE'][batch_index].numpy().decode()

        # Convert the raw frames data from a string to a flat array of floats
        raw_frames_data = tf.io.decode_raw(record['FRAMES_ARRAY'][batch_index], tf.uint8)
        converted_dict['FRAMES_ARRAY'] = tf.reshape(raw_frames_data, [converted_dict['NUM_FRAMES'],
                                                                      converted_dict['HEIGHT'],
                                                                      converted_dict['WIDTH'],
                                                                      converted_dict['CHANNEL_DEPTH']]).numpy()

        return converted_dict


def main():
    print (tf.__version__)
    record_generator =  TfrecordLoader('test_tfrecords/',10)

    # Cycle through the dataset
    for record_batch in record_generator:
        # convert the first record in the batch
        converted_record = record_generator.convert_tfrecorddata_to_dict(record_batch,0)

        # view the first frame of the video
        squeezed_img = converted_record['FRAMES_ARRAY'][0].squeeze()
        cv2.imshow(converted_record['RECORD_NAME'], squeezed_img)
        cv2.waitKey(200)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: @Run_Script i've added the code for data generator.

Comment: Great! I've just proposed an edit that I hope will improve the post's formatting and clarity, but I will upvote once the edit has been made.